# typescript interface: how to implements the interface which merge function interface and property interface

Tags: typescript, interface, implements

typescript interface: how to implements the interface which merge function interface and property interface. eg:

```
interface keyMap {
  name: string;
  mark: number;
}

let keyMapInstance: keyMap = { name: 'John', mark: 85 }

interface development extends keyMap {
  (code: string): void
}
```

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `development` has both a call signature (which can be satisfied by the function) and members (from inheriting `keymap`).You can't define such an object in one step in Typescript (or Javascript for that matter). When you assign the function the compiler complains that the properties are missing (as it should since they are not there yet). You could do one of two things:

**Use `Object.assign` to build the object in one step**

```
var me: development = Object.assign((code: string)=> console.log(code), keyMapInstance)
```

**Use a type assertion and finish the initialization later**

```
var me: development = <development>((code)=> console.log(code))
me.mark = 10;
me.name ="";
```

***Variant: Make the fields optional,and finish the initialization later***

```
interface development extends Partial<keyMap> {
    (code: string): void
}

var me: development = (code)=> console.log(code)
me.mark = 10;
me.name ="";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering, I understood

Answer (score 0):

In the `development` interface, I believe you're trying to declare a `void` function that takes a `string` argument. That should be done like this:

```
interface development extends keyMap {
  fn: (code: string) => void
}
```

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20keyMap%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20mark%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20development%20extends%20keyMap%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fn%3A%20(code%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%3A%20development%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27bar%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mark%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fn%3A%20(x%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(x)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Actually it depends what he is trying to achieve, it is perfectly valid to have an interface with a call signature as in the question.